# Evaluating Expressions on Server-side Swift

Tags: linux, swift, swift3, nsexpression

What is the equivalent of NSExpression to evaluate numeric expressions on the server using Swift ?
Is there a library that enable that ?

I'm getting this error when trying to use NSExpression on Linux:

> fatal error: init(format:_:) is not yet implemented: file Foundation/NSExpression.swift, line 140

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NSExpression** does not provide an initializer that just takes a `format`.
Maybe you were going for

`init(format: String, argumentArray: [Any])`

or

`init(format: String, arguments: CVaListPointer)`

**EDITED**

As of 2016.12.27, most methods in NSExpression - including the `init` methods - **[have not yet been implemented](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/19249417b01573bd6aa32b9a24cc42273315a48b/Foundation/NSExpression.swift).**

Comment: Both shows "not yet implemented" in Swift in Linux.

Comment: thanks for the input, I ended up using https://github.com/nicklockwood/Expression

Comment: @franck ya no problem!

Comment: Sadly, this remains true as of 2/2019.